# Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development - quizzes

Tags: magento2, certification

Fundamentals of Magento 2 Development ( https://u.magento.com/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development#.WkajSSOBiqA ) contains quizzes. How many attempts is there to solve the quiz? 
There is only vague information "Once you start, your attempt is considered as counted, even if you do not submit or answer any questions."
But can't find any info, if there is only single attempt allowed, or if the quiz can be repeated (if so - how many times)?

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember only being given one attempt that actually counted, and possibly only that one at all, for that matter. I took the quizzes months ago, but they might have changed things. Your best bet would be to email Magento U and ask them directly. You can find the training email on the bottom of this page [Training FAQ](https://u.magento.com/training/faq)